# why the following program gives -80 as output?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
    #define ABC 20
#define XYZ 10
#define XXX ABC - XYZ

main()
{
int     a;
a = XXX * 10;
printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

I checked XXX has the value 10. Then why is the output -80? This could  be silly but, I am new to c programming.

Comment: You missed the operator preceedence

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: I hope this is only an exercise. You never would write code like this in the real world. BTW what result did you expect?

Comment: @Michael Walz are you naturally dumb or playing dumb? If XXX is 10..basic multiplication tables suggests 10*10 is 100. If you still can't understand, may god help you!

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
a = XXX * 10;
```

is the same as

```
a = ABC - XYZ * 10;
```

which is

```
a = 20 - 10 * 10;
```

the answer is `20 -100`, `-80`.

That is why, in general, it is advised to make use of parentheses in MACRO definition. Something like

```
  #define XXX (ABC - XYZ)
```

is what you were *expecting*.

That said, the conforming signature of `main()` in a hosted environment is `int main(void)`, at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is, how the preprocessor works. Defines does not create a partial expression or a statement. Instead the macro is literally replaced by its definition.

Therefore in

```
a = XXX * 10;
```

XXX is literally replaces by

```
ABC - XYZ
```

what results in

```
a = ABC - XYZ * 10;
```

Because `*` has a higher binding than `-`, it is

```
a = ABC - (XYZ * 10);
```

which is -80.

It is a good idea to at least write parenthesis around expressions in macros:

```
#define XXX (ABC - XYZ)
```